# Ansible expect responding to multi-line prompty

Tags: ansible, podman, nextcloud

I'm trying to use ansible to run and approve a nextcloud occ command:

```yaml
- name: run encrypt-all
  ansible.builtin.expect:
    command: "podman exec -u www-data {{ nc_container_id }} php occ encryption:encrypt-all"
    responses:
      .*Do you really want to continue.*: "y"
```

The command outputs like this:

```json
{
    "stdout": "\r\n\r\nYou are about to encrypt all files stored in your Nextcloud installation.\r\nDepending on the number of available files, and their size, this may take quite some time.\r\nPlease ensure that no user accesses their files during this time!\r\nNote: The encryption module you use determines which files get encrypted.\r\n\r\nDo you really want to continue? (y/n) aborted",
    "stdout_lines": [
        "",
        "",
        "You are about to encrypt all files stored in your Nextcloud installation.",
        "Depending on the number of available files, and their size, this may take quite some time.",
        "Please ensure that no user accesses their files during this time!",
        "Note: The encryption module you use determines which files get encrypted.",
        "",
        "Do you really want to continue? (y/n) aborted"
    ]
}
```

Where the "aborted" is added after a command is sent.

I've tried quite a few regexes:

- `\nDo you really want to continue.*: "y"` -
- `\\nDo you really want to continue.*: "y"`
- `(?m)^Do you really want to continue.*: "y"`
- `.*Do you really want to continue? \\(y/n\\).*: "y"`

but sadly I get this response for each:

```json
{
    "msg": "non-zero return code",
    "rc": 1,
}
```

Anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So in the end it turned out it wasn't the regex that was the problem.

I had missed an `-i` flag to run podman interactively.

the ansible task should have been:

```yaml
- name: run encrypt-all
  ansible.builtin.expect:
    command: "podman exec -iu www-data {{ nc_container_id }} php occ encryption:encrypt-all"
    responses:
      (?m)^Do you really want to continue.*: "y"
```